# Deploy WAR to TomEE server

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, war, apache-tomee, tomee-7

I built my JavaEE project & got **my-service.war** file. I want to deploy it to [TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/installing-tomee.html) server.

I have successfully installed TomEE (I can start & stop TomEE server successfully).

I copy **my-service.war** to

```
<TomEE_Home>/webapps/
```

Then, I start TomeEE server.

I open my browser, and put URL http://localhost:8080/my-service

But I get HTTP Status 404 page.

(Then, I checked under /webapps/ that, my-server.war has been unzipped by server, because I see my-server folder there.)

What do I miss for deploying my WAR to TomEE server?

**=====server logs =====**

I got checked /logs/catalina.2016-08-16.log , I see these errors:

```
webapps/my-service/WEB-INF/classes/ looking all classes to find CDI beans, maybe think to add a beans.xml if not there or add the jar to exclusions.list
...
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/my-service] startup failed due to previous errors
16-Aug-2016 13:51:46.311 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication Undeploying app: /Users/xichen/Dev-tools/apache-tomee-webprofile-7.0.1/webapps/my-service
```

Comment: shouldn't you try `http://localhost:8080/my-service/` instead of `http://localhost:8080/my-service`

Comment: Tried, same error. Do I need to configure the server for my app? in conf/server.xml?? If so, what should I configure there?

Comment: are you using eclipse ?

Comment: No, I built my project with maven, I get the war after built it. Then, I copy WAR to <TomeEE_HOME>/webapps/ , then, I started my server with command line. That's it.

Comment: Anything helpful in your log-file ([TomEE_Home]/logs/catalina.xxxx.xx.xx.log)?

Comment: updated my question with logs information

Comment: Do you have a beans.xml in your project?

Comment: The top line is not an error, only a tip for better results. The true deployment error is still not shown here.

Comment: When you get a second, post the entire startup log :)

Answer (score 1):

You should check logs/catalina.date.log and logs/localhost..log files.

If you are under unix execute:

```
grep SEVERE logs/*
```

to get the errors.

The real error associated with

```
Context [/my-service] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Is before in the logs

Comment: I know the real error associated with that line of log, that's why I also provided the previous error in my question. And the localhost.2016-08-16.log file is empty.

Comment: I'm not seeing it, if you reference "webapps/my-service/WEB-INF/classes/ looking all classes to find CDI beans, maybe think to add a beans.xml if not there or add the jar to exclusions.list
..." this is not an error and not the one triggering the undeployment